# Android: Center background shape in textView

Tags: android, xml, android-styles

I use shape as background in TextView.

But I have no idea how can I center text.

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPVnE.png)

My shape:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
            <corners android:radius="30.0dip" />
            <size
                android:height="50dp"
                android:width="190dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Styles:

```
 <style name="AppTheme.TextView" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/text_view_shape</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

My Layout                                                                                   :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/tutorial_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/img_two"
tools:context="com.....TutorialFragment">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/tutorial_new_job"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    style="@style/AppTheme.TextView"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/tutorial_its_easy"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    style="@style/AppTheme.TextView"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Comment: Kindly share your layout too.

Comment: android:gravity="center"

Comment: @anonymous oh, it centered text in vertical. But text stands in the left. How to center in horyzontal?

Comment: set textview width matchparent and add  
android:gravity="center"

Comment: Did you try to use shape drawable without size? It may be the reason.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
            <corners android:radius="30.0dip" />
            <size
                android:height="50dp"
                android:width="190dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="50dp"
                android:right="50dp">
            </padding>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

plus *android:gravity="center"* for TextView

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` or `android:textAlignment="center_horizontal"`